# Class Issues involving an Array

Tags: java, class, search, for-loop

I'm attempting to make an array of `WordCount`s, then iterate through a file line by line separating it into tokens using a split method. Then for each token, if it's in `wordList`, increment `count`, and if it's not in `wordList` just simply add it to the list.

`Hmwk` class -

```
public class Hmwk {        
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int n=0;
        WordCount[] wordList= new WordCount[10000];
        Scanner words = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        while (words.hasNextLine() && n < 10000) {
            String line = words.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split("[^\\p{Alpha}]");
            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                if (tokens[i].length() > 0) {
                    WordCount word = new WordCount(tokens[i]);
                    int foundAt = search(wordList, word, n);
                    if (foundAt >= 0) {
                        word.increment();
                    } else {
                        wordList[n]=word;
                        n++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Arrays.sort(wordList);
        String alphabeticFileName = "alphabetic.txt";
        String frequencyFilename = "frequency.txt";
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(alphabeticFileName);
        for (int i=0; i < n;i++) {
            output.println(wordList[i].toString());
        }
        output.close();
        //Sort on frequency somehow
        PrintWriter output2 = new PrintWriter(frequencyFilename);
        for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
            output2.println(wordList[i].toString());
        }
        output2.close();

    }

    public static int search(WordCount[] list,WordCount word, int n) {
        int result = -1;
        int i=0;
        while (result < 0 && i < n) {
            if (word == list[i]) {
                result = i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }        
}
```

`WordCount` class -

```
class WordCount {        
    String word;
    int count;
    static boolean compareByWord;

    public WordCount(String aWord) {
        setWord(aWord);
        count = 1;
    }

    private void setWord(String theWord) {
        word = theWord;
    }

    public void increment() {
        count += 1;
    }

    public static void sortByWord() {
        compareByWord = true;
    }

    public static void sortByCount() {
        compareByWord = false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = String.format("%s (%d)", word, count);
        return result;
    }        
}
```

It compiles and runs fine, but for some reason I'm given

```
Peter (1)
Piper (1)
picked (1)
a (1)
peck (1)
of (1)
pickled (1)
peppers (1)
A (1)
peck (1)
of (1)
pickled (1)
peppers (1)
Peter (1)
Piper (1)
picked (1)
If (1)
Peter (1)
Piper (1)
picked (1)
a (1)
peck (1)
of (1)
pickled (1)
peppers (1)
Where (1)
s (1)
the (1)
peck (1)
of (1)
pickled (1)
peppers (1)
that (1)
Peter (1)
Piper (1)
picked (1)
```

as output. Is there something wrong with my class, or my search method here? I'm lost, any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without reading through your code too carefully, it seems the problem is here:

```
        if (foundAt >= 0)
        {
            word.increment();
        }
```

Here you increment the "new" word not the one previously added.
Should be something like:

```
        if (foundAt >= 0)
        {
            wordList[foundAt].increment();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `search` method's signature as follows -

```
public static WordCount search(WordCount[] list, String word)
```

You only need to pass the array and the current token (word or string), and the method should return the `WordCount` for the word or null if not found. That way you don't need to deal with the index, and don't need to create an instance of `WordCount` for current word if it's already in the array.

One, bug in your `search` method is `word == list[i]`. That's not how you check object equality, instead you should use the [`.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method for that purpose.

Now, after changing `search` method's signature, within the method, you would loop through the `list` array, compare the word inside each `WordCount` (i.e. `list[i]`) with current array element, `tokens[i]`, and if they are equal then immediately return current `WordCount` (i.e. `list[i]`).

Then you will call the `search` method as follows -

```
WordCount wordCount = search(wordList, tokens[i]);
```

Then immediately check if `wordCount` is null. If it's null then create new instance of `WordCount` for the current word (i.e. `tokens[i]`) and put it in the array. And if it's not null then just increment it's count (`wordCount.increment()`).