# Searching through Objects Issue

Tags: java, class, search, if-statement, for-loop

The program is to find all of the words in a text file and count how many times each word is found.  Our definition of a "word" will be relatively crude and will be done by splitting the line based on characters that are not alphabetic. I know there are easier ways to go about this but we were required to use a class and a search method like the one I attempted. I can't figure out why it's not incrementing `word`'s that are already in `wordList`. I believe it's either completely skipping over my `if (foundAt >=0`, or it's not incrementing it correctly, I'm leaning toward my `search` method being wrong, but I can't figure out the problem. Any and all help is much appreciated, thanks for your time.

```
public class Hmwk {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int n=0;
    WordCount[] wordList= new WordCount[10000];
    Scanner words = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    while (words.hasNextLine() && n < 10000)
    {
        String line = words.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split("[^\\p{Alpha}]");
        for (int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++)
        {
            if (tokens[i].length()>0)
            {
                WordCount word = new WordCount(tokens[i]);
                int foundAt = search(wordList, word, n);
                if (foundAt >= 0)
                {
                    wordList[foundAt].increment();
                }
                else
                {
                    wordList[n]=word;
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Arrays.sort(wordList);
    String alphabeticFileName = "alphabetic.txt";
    String frequencyFilename = "frequency.txt";
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(alphabeticFileName);
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        output.println(wordList[i].toString());
    }
    output.close();
    //Sort on frequency somehow
    PrintWriter output2 = new PrintWriter(frequencyFilename);
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        output2.println(wordList[i].toString());
    }
    output2.close();


}
public static int search(WordCount[] list,WordCount word, int n)
{
    int result = -1;
    int i=0;
    while (result < 0 && i < n)
    {
        if (word.equals(list[i]))
        {
            result = i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}

}
class WordCount
{
String word;
int count;
static boolean compareByWord;
public WordCount(String aWord)
{
    setWord(aWord);
    count = 1;
}
private void setWord(String theWord)
{
    word=theWord;
}
public void increment()
{
    count=+1;
}
public static void sortByWord()
{
    compareByWord = true;
}
public static void sortByCount()
{
    compareByWord = false;
}
public String toString()
{
    String result = String.format("%s (%d)",word, count);
    return result;
}
}
```

Output:

```
Peter (1)
Piper (1)
picked (1)
a (1)
peck (1)
of (1)
pickled (1)
peppers (1)
A (1)
peck (1)
of (1)
pickled (1)
peppers (1)
```

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23072388/738746

Comment: @BheshGurung that was my roommate. He got his program working correctly using your method and says he appreciated the quick detailed response, but I'm trying to stay with my style. I just can't figure out where I'm going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Your increment function is wrong. You've written:

```
count =+1;
```

Which only sets the count to one. To increment count by one you put:

```
count += 1;
```